# Double Linked List: Removing Node C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
void DLinkedList::removeName(const Elem& name) {

 DNode * node = header;

 if (node != NULL) {
     do {
         if(node->elem == name){
             node->prev->next = node->next;  
             node->next->prev = node->prev;
             delete node;
         }
         node = node->next;
     } while (node != header); // Stop when we reach the head again.
 }

}
```

I threw it into the debugger and after my about 3rd pass through the if(node->elem == name) it crashes for reasons im not too sure of.

Comment: The reason is probably an invalid pointer being dereferenced...

Comment: `delete node; node = node->next;` - you're accessing memory you just freed.

Comment: assuming you fix the dereference error, how do you deal with the deletion of the first element?

Answer (score 0):

Note how if the condition is true, then you `delete node` and later dereference it at `node->next`, causing *undefined behavior* which is what's causing your crash there

```
     if(node->elem == name){
         node->prev->next = node->next;  
         node->next->prev = node->prev;
         delete node; // delete here
     }
     node = node->next; // dereference invalid pointer
```

Comment: Yes I added a break after delete node; Thank you for your help